# Firebase 3 update local cache

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an iOS app that receives data from Firebase database. I need to keep a local version of the DB and I found really awesome the offline capability of Firebase. Now,

1. Is there any way to disable auto sync and only update when the user click some button?
2. Is there any way to only update new or modified elements instead of re-download everything?

2-bis. Is there any way to know each element that has been added/modified?

3. Does FIRDataSnapshot conform to NSCoding protocol? I'd like to save it locally in a plist file...

EDIT:

After reading more in Firebase 3 documentation, I'm now looking to get all DB tree in a single request, is it possible?

My code is the following

```
    FIRDatabaseReference.goOnline()    
    var firebase = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath("items")
            firebase.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

                print(snapshot.value)

                if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                    for snap in snapshots {

                        if let postDictionary = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                           print ("item received")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }) 
FIRDatabaseReference.goOffline()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. You can programmatically control when data gets loaded by using [`observeSingleEventOfType`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data#read_data_once).
2. Not when using `observeSingleEventOfType`, because with that you're effectively disabling Firebase's cache.
3. `FIRDataSnapshot` does not conform to NSCoding protocol

Comment: I found in the docs the goOnline() and goOffline() methods and I think they will let me do what I'm trying to do (1), do you have some experiance using these methods? The firebase 3 docs is not really helpul

Comment: Calling `goOffline()` and `goOnline()` allows you to programmatically control whether Firebase is connected to its servers. For related questions, see [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D%5Bios%5D+gooffline). If you're having trouble getting part of the code to work, show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks you're being really helpful, actually I'm trying to understand how can i use all the firebase capabilities to solve a really simple problem. Is there any way to download the DB's tree in a JSON format?

Comment: The iOS SDK doesn't expose raw JSON afaik. If you don't want none of the realtime stuff, you're probably better off using the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data).

Comment: Awesome! That's really what I was looking for thanks a lot!